# RTC DS1307 VCC not getting connected to 5V of Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, rtc

I am using RTC DS1307 with "TINY RTC I2C modules" written on it.I had downloaded RTClib library from adafruit and using the example code. I connected GND->GND, VCC->5V, SDA->A4 and SCL->A5. However after connecting the VCC to 5V the "ON" Led does not lights up and the code is not getting uploaded. I tried connecting the VCC to 3.3 V the code gets uploaded but does not shows any output on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

It seems an hardware problem on Arduino Uno board.

Try to connect the 5V pin of Arduino Uno to a digital pin (e.g D7) and write a program for read a digital pin.

```
int inPin = 7;     // digital pin 7
int val = 0;       // variable to store the read value

void setup()
{
  pinMode(inPin, INPUT);        // sets the digital pin 7 as input
}

void loop()
{
  val = digitalRead(inPin);     // read the input pin
  Serial.println(val);          // print read value on serial
}
```

If you're **not** able to load this sketch on your Arduino, most likely it's an hardware problem on Arduino.

Comment: But 5V of Arduino is drawing current to VCC of bluetooth HC05 module

Comment: You remove temporary the HC 05 module and try it.

Comment: I had tried that and I think there is some hardware problem with my RTC.

Answer (score 1):

Soldering was not done properly. The vcc and ground got "short" that's what the shopkeeper said. We again soldered it on the other side. Now its working

Answer (score 0):

Just another point,

From my experience, any module that uses a serial connection can disrupt the sketch uploading process to the Arduino.

The best is to upload to Arduino when all serial connections are dis-connected.